# How to prove $2^{\sqrt{f(n)}} \in O\ (2^{f(n)})$ if $f:\Bbb{N}\rightarrow \Bbb{R^+}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, algorithms, computer-science, real-numbers

How to prove $2^{\sqrt{f(n)}} \in O\ (2^{f(n)})$ if $f:\Bbb{N}\rightarrow \Bbb{R^+}$?

So we want to prove $\exists c\in\Bbb{R^+}:\ [\exists B\in\Bbb{N}:[\ \forall 
n\in\Bbb{N}:\ n\ge B\rightarrow 2^{\sqrt{f(n)}} \le c(2^{f(n)}))]]$

But we don't know what the function does, so how are we supposed to make the connection, i.e. $2^{\sqrt{f(n)}} \ge g(n)\ge c(2^{f(n)}))$?

Comment: Note that the last inequality in "we want to prove" goes the wrong way -- it should be $2^{\sqrt{f(n)}} \le c\cdot 2^{f(n)}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $f(n)+1 \ge \sqrt{f(n)}$ no matter what $f(n)$ is.

Comment: +1, this answer makes sense to me. BTW, is it necessary for $f$ to have $\textrm{Dom}(f)=\Bbb N$ ? My thinking suggests that this should hold for any real-valued function.

Comment: To prove this fact, use $\left(\sqrt{x}-1\right)\geq0$, and $\sqrt{x} \geq 0$.